# Serve static content on Jetty, that are resources on WEB-INF/lib libraries?

Tags: java, servlets, jar, jetty, war

For a project that I'm working on (using Jetty 9), I'm interested in setting up DefaultServlet  on web.xml and serve static content.
The particularity is that I want to deploy a war file, which itself packages modules of the application in individual jars that are included in /WEB-INF/lib.
On one of these jars I am packaging a static content resource directory, that should be configured as the base of files for DefaultServlet on WAR's webxml.

So far I have this in my WAR's WEB-INF/web.xml

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dashboard</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.resourceBase</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/static/</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dashboard</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dashboard</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</servlet>
```

Inside the WAR, WEB-INF/lib/dashboard.jar's structure is:

```
/
/static/index.html
/META-INF
```

Ideally I would like to access /dashboard/index.html

I know that the following config is wrong, but it transmits what I think it should be possible, i.e. set the base of content served of DefaultServlet with a "classpath path", that could be embedded in one of the WAR's jar...

```
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.resourceBase</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/static/</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

Any experts out there who can provide an hint on how I can get this to work ?

Thanks